# BTEQ query not returning all the columns

Tags: unix, teradata

I am creating a unix script to get null counts of each column in a table in one go(USING BTEQ). My query is like :
select count(*) - count(column_name1), count(*) - count(column_name2).... from table_name; 
The query returns 1 row and the no. of columns with its null count. I have more than 900 columns in one table. But the query is not able to return only 818 columns when running in BTEQ. Is there any solution to return all the columns and store the count in a file.

Comment: Have you tried using `RETLIMIT`?  I haven't used it for columns before, but it looks like it may work unless you run into some other system limitation.  Try adding this to the beginning of your bteq script: `.SET RETLIMIT * *;` This should return the max rows / columns. 
 https://docs.teradata.com/reader/jmAxXLdiDu6NiyjT6hhk7g/BlQdS7Ev5SEJADEngyHd_Q

Comment: Need to supply more information regarding what you are trying and what you want to achieve. What controls are set, in particular the WIDTH for the output? Are you sending the counts to STDOUT or is this a BTEQ EXPORT (and if so, what format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following SET commands for viewing columns in Bteq console

```
$ bteq

 Enter your logon or BTEQ command:
.logon $HOST/$USER
Password: $PASS

.Set Format off
.Set Recordmode off
.Set Echoreq on
.Set Separator '|'
.width 3000
.Set Titledashes on


SELECT * FROM <DB>.<TABLE>;
```

Comment: .Set Format off
.Set Recordmode off
.Set Echoreq on
.Set Separator '|'
.width 200 
.Set Titledashes on

Answer (score 0):

.Set Format off
.Set Recordmode off
.Set Echoreq on
.Set Separator '|'
**.width 200**
.Set Titledashes on

chnage to  200  doesn't work.