# how to show more column in tera data bteq?

Tags: teradata

i have selected a sql command which have more than one column in result, but only display one in screen.
see the result below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/21wBy.jpg

this is not work
[BTEQ query not returning all the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455652/bteq-query-not-returning-all-the-columns)

Comment: `.set width 1048575;` doesn't work?

Comment: set it  width 3000.  SHOW too many space.  set it to 100.  only show one column.

Comment: The output of BTEQ is fixed width based on the defined column size. You might CAST each column to a shorter length or switch to a more modern client like Studio.

Comment: how to cast a string to fix length?  Sorry  I'm new at this.

Comment: You can  Answer me below  I'll chose you the correct answer .  Thanks  a lot.

Comment: `CAST(col AS CHAR(20))`, but might be VARCHAR, too, BTEQ pads with trailing spaces. Btw, WIDTH in BTEQ is the overall width, not the width per column (BTEQ was used a report generator)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Avqf1io    answer me  below.   copy paste your answer below. I'll chose you the correct answer . Thanks a lot.